# Should a method ending in ? (question mark) return only a boolean?

Tags: ruby

I think it's just common sense and Ruby convention to do this but I have this method:

```
def is_subscribed?(feed_url)
  Subscription.find_by_user_id_and_feed_id(self[ :id ], Feed.find_by_feed_url(feed_url))
end
```

The only confusion I'm getting is, this doesn't return boolean like I originally anticipated by putting the question mark on the end of the method name. I was under the impression that when evaluating an object as conditional it returns `true` if not `nil`.

Apparently I'm missing the point here and it's not evaluating it like I thought.

So, my question is, would it be best to just do an `if (condition) true else false`? Or is there a more elegant method of doing this?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

A method ending with ? should return a value which can be meaningfully evaluated to true or false. If you want to ensure a boolean return, you can do so by adding a double bang to the finder.

```
def is_subscribed?(feed_url)
  !!Subscription.find_by_user_id_and_feed_id(self[ :id ], Feed.find_by_feed_url(feed_url))
end
```

Comment: As an aside, maybe the method should be named as "subscribed?". "?" already conveys the sense of "is".

Comment: “a value which can be evaluated to true or false”, but any and every value in Ruby does evaluate to `true` or `false`…

Comment: everything in ruby evaluates to true except for nil and false

Comment: You are right Andrew. It should be "return a value which can **meaningfully** be evaluated to true of false".

Answer (score 22):

Adding a `?` to the end of a method name does not in any way change the return value of the method, but instead only indicates that it is a *predicate method*. That is, that the method's return value should be treated as a boolean, but does not need to be strictly boolean (i.e. `true` or `false`).

Many of the other answers state that it should return a value that is truthy or falsy. This is rather redundant, since *everything* can be either truthy or falsy, and since all methods in Ruby return something (unless they raise an exception), the return value is *always* truthy or falsy.

Think of appending a `?` as a nicer alternative to prepending `is_` in other languages; e.g. I would either have `subscribed?` or `is_subscribed`.

Answer (score 6):

It should a 'truthy' or 'falsy' value, that can be used safely in predicates, but does not have to return literal `true` or `false`. There are even methods like this, like [`File.size?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/File.html#method-c-size-3F), in the standard library.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, to be specific -- methods ending in a question mark should return values that can be tested as `true` or `false`.

There are many methods in rails that return non-boolean values from '?' methods.

In fact there was recently a pull request submitted to the rails project that focussed attention on this exact matter:

https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/5582

Basically, the discussion was around this exact issue -- methods only need to return values that can be tested as true or false, like so:

```
if (condition)
  # do 'truthy option
else
  # do non-truthy option
end
```

From that perspective, I believe your method is fine.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers cover the return value very well.

I'll add that modern style guides discourage the `is_` prefix to boolean methods. The trailing question mark covers that semantic sugar.

From https://github.com/rubocop-hq/ruby-style-guide:

> Boolean Methods Question Mark
>
> The names of predicate methods (methods
> that return a boolean value) should end in a question mark (i.e.
> Array#empty?). Methods that don’t return a boolean, shouldn’t end in a
> question mark.
>
> Boolean Methods Prefix
>
> Avoid prefixing predicate methods with the
> auxiliary verbs such as is, does, or can. These words are redundant
> and inconsistent with the style of boolean methods in the Ruby core
> library, such as empty? and include?.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to use a ternary/conditional operator to enforce a boolean return.

```
 if_this_is_a_true_value ? then_the_result_is_this : else_it_is_this
```

I do agree with others in changing your method name to

```
 def subscribed?
```